# Add bootstrap modal form on page exit

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

Is there any way to show bootstrap form in joomla 3.0 when user wants to exit page ? 
I'm trying to add custom html page with position closest to footer. 
When I'm trying to test this feature I'm facing 1 error:
1: ` TypeError: Cannot read property 'modal' of null;

Below my code from my custom html module.

```
     <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Contact Form</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form role="form" action="" method="post" >
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="InputName">Name</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputName" id="InputName" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="InputEmail"> e-mail</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" name="InputEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" required  >
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="InputMessage">Message</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <textarea name="InputMessage" id="InputMessage" class="form-control" rows="5" required></textarea>
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span></div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Wyślij" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
    </div>
  </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zamknij</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
    <script type='text/javascript'>

function goodbye(e) {
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
    $('#myModal').modal('show');    
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?'; //This is displayed on the dialog
   $('#test').show();

    //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload=goodbye; 

</script>
```

Is there any way to display only modal without browser's alert message?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the bootstrap framework (Which I'm sure you already have).

I believe you also need to initialize the html element to modal before calling the show method.

```
$('#myModal').modal({'show':true});
```

Please see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/y4zqd3b9/3/

Also, what is the #test for?

More information: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods